# Generating Swing forms and validating user input in Java?

Tags: java, swing

Is there any library out there that would generate user forms in Swing JFrame from a model like the following **and** verify user input with defined constraints from the model?

```
<SomeObject>
  <FirstParameter name="firstParameter" displayName="First" 
dataType="Integer" min="1" max="100" />
  <SecondParameter name="secondParameter" displayName="Second" dataType="String">
    <PossibleValue value="Dog" />
    <PossibleValue value="Mouse" />
  </SecondParameter>
</SomeObject>
```

So the lib should generate JTextField for the "FirstParameter" and JList for the "SecondParameter". After pushing "submit" button the user should get pop-ups if some data is incorrect (does not fulfill constraints). It would be nice to have regular expressions in order to check data.

Comment: If you know all the permitted values, why not use a JListBox instead?

Comment: Sorry, rushed typo/bad memory. I meant a read-only JComboBox.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Or a [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: @James McLeod: JComboBox would be ok too or maybe even better.